# Querying metadata - Find Custom fields created today

Tags: custom-field, metadata, schema

I am looking to find the "Custom" fields that were created "today" within an object in Salesforce.com. There are more than 500 fields on the object and the "Modified By" field in the schema is not sortable.

Object can be Standard or Custom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I discovered this yesterday. Open your Developer Console, click on the Query Editor tab, click the "Use Tooling API" checkbox, then query away!

```
SELECT DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
```

If you want to limit it to a single table, you can also filter by TableEnumOrId:

## Standard Object

```
SELECT DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY AND TableEnumOrId = 'Account'
```

## Custom Object

```
SELECT DeveloperName, TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY AND TableEnumOrId = '01I...'
```

WHere 01I... is the Id of the custom object, which you can get from the following query:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM CustomObject WHERE DeveloperName = 'CustomObj'
```

Note that DeveloperName in the Tooling API never uses __c.